# How to flush requests faster to client using curl for apns on http/2

Tags: php, curl, http2

Hello this php script using curl takes close to 10 min to complete the sending of 2500 push notifications on Apple HTTP/2 APNS server.

How can I accelerate the number of http request sent to the same server if the url changes every time.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_PORT => 443,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_alert,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
));
// send push for each token
foreach ($all_tokens as $device_token) {
  $url = "{$base_url}/3/device/{$device_token}";
  // set url per device token
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  // go...
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  // get response
  $status = curl_getinfo($curl);
  if ($status['http_code'] == '410') {
    // device does not accept push for this app anymore
    $bad_tokens[] = $device_token;
  } else if($status['http_code'] == '200') {
    $push_sent_succss_count += 1;
  }
}
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Try it asynchron... i mean more instances with this job

Comment: im currently looking at this https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html the multiplexing part

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP's [cURL multi handle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php), or use a library, such as Guzzle, with [batching functions](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/batching/batching.html).

These will allow you to send the requests in parallel and either handle the responses as they arrive or wait for the last/ slowest one and handle all the responses then.

Comment: I'm looking into this. I read someone was batching close to a thousand request on a multi handle like you proposed, so I guess it could be the way.